# Is it possible to tell browsers (chrome?) the correct URL for a language?

Tags: html, google-chrome, translation

I have a website that has various translations available via:

```
http://example.com/en/...
http://example.com/de/...
http://example.com/es/...
etc...
```

Whenever I go to one of the non-english sites, Chrome pops up it's "Would you like to translate this page?" bar.  If I click "translate to english", it runs the page through it's translation backend and, of course, spits out somewhat broken english.

I'd prefer it to simply redirect to `http://example.com/en/...`.  Is there any way to flag this to the browser?  I already have a language selector in the page, but people might not notice it / may be unable to read it, and the google translate bar is so in your face.

Comment: Could you please clarify one thing?  This website - is this yours, i.e. do you control the code for the site?  Or is this some other site on the web?

Comment: Just re-read your comment about the language selector - thus I assume this is your site.  That will make the task easier....

Comment: @EJK - yes, it's my site

Comment: What is the server technology?  JSP?  ASP?  something else?

Comment: @EJK - custom node.js, though it doesn't really matter.  I'm looking for specs on either server headers or markup to embed in the page

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I got it.  This is from https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/DWewxpX1tLE:

```
If you would prefer your webpage not be 
translated by Google Translate, insert the following meta tag into your 
HTML files:

<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

This will at least suppress the translate bar.  It won't however handle the desired redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the `Accept-Language` http header of the request and do a redirect based on that. But make sure that your language selector sets a cookie that you give preference over the `Accept-Language` header. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation#The_Accept-Language.3A_header for some background information.